# How to add drop down Value by JavaScript Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, append, appendchild

I getting values form API and now I want to add these value to a drop down list.I tried this way:
My HTML :

```
    <div class="job-filter-dropdown same-pad location">
                                <select class="selectpicker" id="location">
                                    <option value="" selected>Location</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
```

and I wrote function from where I am trying to add value which is:

```
   function loadLoc(data){
                len = data.length;
                console.log(data);
                for(x=0;x<len;x++){
                         $('#location').append('<option value="california">'+data[x].name+'</option>');
                          }
                       }
```

what I did wrong :(

Comment: Maybe `$('#location')` is empty. Were do you call this function? After, before the select or in jQuery Ready function?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I have updated it so try this: [link](https://codepen.io/mark-minerov/pen/VwLNbaX)

HTML

```html
<div class="job-filter-dropdown same-pad location">
  <select class="selectpicker" id="location">
    <option value="" selected>Location</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
  function loadLoc(data) {
    len = data.length

    console.log(data)

    for(let item of data) {
      $('#location').append(`<option value="california">${ item.name }</option>`)
    }

  }

const list = [
  { name: 'California' },
  { name: "Russia" },
  { name: "Israel" }
]

window.onload = () => {
  loadLoc(list)
}
```